# No matching signature for operator IN for argument types STRING and {ARRAY<STRING>} (Google BigQuery)

Tags: ruby, google-bigquery

I'm using Google BigQuery Ruby Client v0.23 and trying to use parameterized queries. I'm following [API docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud-bigquery/v0.23.0/google/cloud/bigquery) for reference.

When I run queries without the params, all is fine. However to make them dynamic, when I use an array params I get error. E.g. When I run this query

```
bigquery.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oven.sensor_counts WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2016-04-04') AND sensor_id IN (@sensor_ids)", params: { sensor_ids: ['48-6', '48-2'] })
```

I get this

```
#<Harley::Response POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/sensors-160421/queries == 400 (413 bytes) 3458ms>
Caught error invalidQuery: No matching signature for operator IN for argument types STRING and {ARRAY<STRING>} at [1:116]
Error - #<Google::Apis::ClientError: invalidQuery: No matching signature for operator IN for argument types STRING and {ARRAY<STRING>} at [1:116]>

Google::Cloud::InvalidArgumentError: invalidQuery: No matching signature for operator IN for argument types STRING and {ARRAY<STRING>} at [1:116]
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/google-cloud-bigquery-0.23.0/lib/google/cloud/bigquery/service.rb:662:in `rescue in execute'
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears to be an issue even with the API examples. https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=873

Comment: There is now an open GitHub issue for this in google-cloud-ruby: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/issues/1185

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe the array is simply an incorrect argument. According to [Functions & Operators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#in-operators), the syntax is:

```
x IN (y, z, ...)
```

Notice that there is no array.

And replacing the array with a single string works:

```
require "google/cloud/bigquery"

bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new

sql = "SELECT word, SUM(word_count) AS word_count " \
      "FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`" \
      "WHERE word IN (@words) GROUP BY word"
data = bigquery.query sql, params: { words: 'you' }
#=> [{"word"=>"you", "word_count"=>12527}]
```

The array argument works with the addition of `UNNEST`, per the syntax guide linked above:

> The UNNEST form treats an array scan like UNNEST in the FROM clause:
>
> `x [NOT] IN UNNEST(<array expression>)`
>
> This form is often used with ARRAY parameters. For example:
>
> `x IN UNNEST(@array_parameter)`

So the solution is:

```
require "google/cloud/bigquery"

bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new

sql = "SELECT word, SUM(word_count) AS word_count " \
      "FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`" \
      "WHERE word IN UNNEST(@words) GROUP BY word"
data = bigquery.query sql, params: { words: ['me', 'I', 'you'] }
#=> [{"word"=>"I", "word_count"=>21028}, {"word"=>"me", "word_count"=>8030}, {"word"=>"you", "word_count"=>12527}]
```

Comment: You saved my life! =)

Comment: UNNEST solved me similar problem for string arrays, but I failed to accomplish it with Date[] . Don't you know about any workaround for Dates?

Answer (score -3):

There is a better way to do this using arrays, [using parameterized approach](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries)

> ## from google.cloud import bigquery
>
> ## client = bigquery.Client()
>
> sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oven.sensor_counts WHERE _PARTITIONTIME =
>   TIMESTAMP('2016-04-04') AND sensor_id IN UNNEST(@sensor_ids)"
>
> query_params = [
>       bigquery.ArrayQueryParameter("sensor_ids", "STRING", ['48-6', '48-2']), ]
>
> job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig() job_config.query_parameters =
>   query_params query_job = client.query(
>       query,
>       job_config=job_config, )    client.query(sql,job_config=query_config)